# 2 instances with same name in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, infrastructure-as-code

I have created 2 instances with autoscaling using terraform and both the instances have the same name. When I try to change the subnets, it's only changing for one instance and not for the 2nd instance.

Could the same name be the reason for this behavior.

Comment: 2 instances of what? What service? EC2? DynamoDB?

Comment: I have created Ec2 instances

Comment: @AdamVincent I have created Ec2 instances

Comment: Show your terraform code in your question.

Comment: resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  name                      = "school_asg"
  launch_configuration      = "${aws_launch_configuration.school.id}"
  min_size                  = 2
  max_size                  = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 150
  desired_capacity          = 2
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${var.subnet_id}"]
  health_check_type         = "EC2"

  tags = [
    {
      key                 = "Name"
      value               = "ECS-dev-instance"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
  ]
}

Comment: The issue is sorted now, it was because of the same name only. I removed the tag and it's working fine now.